# Penalty for Non-State-Changing Texture Rebinding in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics

Changing active textures is an expensive operation in OpenGL. I am in the process of optimizing some code by batching drawn objects by their needed textures. I have already implemented a fix for this problem on the application side but I am wanting an answer to a question that popped up while I did so.

Say I have the following code:

```
bindTexture(tex1);
draw();

changeSomeUniforms();
bindTexture(tex1);    // I rebind the same texture as used above! 
draw();

bindTexture(tex2);
draw();
```

Assuming all textures are getting bound to `GL_TEXTURE0`, is OpenGL capable of ignoring the unnecessary rebind of `tex1` without my intervention? Since the call does not change the state of OpenGL, does OpenGL ignore it?

I currently batch things by similar texture so the above is in my application like so:

```
bindTexture(tex1);
draw();

changeSomeUniforms();
draw();

bindTexture(tex2);
draw();
```

I wanted to know if OpenGL was smarter than me and did not rebind the same texture without my intervention?

Comment: This will depend on the specific implementation. The OpenGL standard doesn't say anything in this regard, so your driver may or may not have this optimization.

Comment: @BDL would you be willing to make your comment an answer that I may set it accordingly? Thank you for the information!